# WordPress query adds INNER/LEFT JOIN. Why or how to remove/prevent INNER/LEFT JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, join, filter

I am working on a filter for posts in WordPress which uses data from postsmeta:
My date filter is working and gives me this query:

**Working query result:**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1 AND YEAR(wp_posts.post_date)=2017 
AND MONTH(wp_posts.post_date)=03 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'projects' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' 
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' 
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

When I filter by postmeta.meta_value I get an extra INNER JOIN which is causing issues:

**Filter *(not exactly working)*:**

```
$query->set('meta_query', array(
   array(
      'key' => 'project_cust_id',
      'value' => $project_cust_id,
      'compare' => '=' 
   )
));
```

**Query *(not working result)*:**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) 
WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'project_cust_id' 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '12345' ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'projects' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' 
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' 
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

When I query this straight into my DB I get no results and error below, but when I remove the extra line: `INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )` or when I remove the line: `LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)`  I do get the results as expected.

**EDIT: MySQL returns error: Not unique value table/alias: 'wp_postmeta'**

My question is:

- Why does my code adds another INNER JOIN?
- How can I remove/prevent this extra INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are filtering (ie, removing non matching records), so a LEFT OUTER JOIN doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I have updated my post/question, cause I could remove either the left or the inner join, in both cases it gives me the result.
But still I dont know how I can remove 1 of those joins from my SQL-statement.

Comment: You don't have data in "wp_postmeta" table but have same data in "wp_posts".

Maybe you need think about why you not have data in "wp_postmeta" for this post_id ?

Comment: MAybe it is because "'compare' => '=' "  ?

Comment: There is data in the wp_postmeta, and the cust_id is not in wp_posts, it gets linked by the post_id in the postmeta to the id in the posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the input, but it turned out that there was nothing wrong with my coding, apparently there was some other plugin wich sended a GET parameter when I sended the filter parameters, this was returning FALSE when this parameter was set, I fixed it by adding !EMPTY in that plugin, after that it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are filtering for values in the wp_postmeta table in your where clause, the `LEFT JOIN` is going to act like an `INNER JOIN`, since it will only return values that have the matching criteria in the wp_postmeta table.  So having a `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` or both should not make a difference. If you want the join to act like a `LEFT JOIN`, any criteria for the wp_postmeta table should be added to the `JOIN` and not the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 

FROM   wp_posts 

       LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta 
       ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
       AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'project_cust_id' 
       AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '12345'

WHERE  1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'projects' 
       AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' 
       OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' 
       OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 

GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 

ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, but I can't/don't know how to alter the query to remove a JOIN from the statement.
And I don't know how to put it in the WHERE clause, could you please write me a code that works with the object $query please? Reference: Filter (not exactly working)

Comment: I mean how to remove it from the WHERE clause, and put it into the JOIN

Answer (score 0):

I found no solution with WP_Query args but one using filter "comments_clauses".

```
public static function get_comments($query){
    add_filter( 'comments_clauses', array(__CLASS__, 'on_get_comments_clauses_cb' ), 10, 2);
    $the_query = new WP_Comment_Query( $query );
    remove_filter( 'comments_clauses', array(__CLASS__, 'on_get_comments_clauses_cb' ), 10);
        
    return $the_query->comments; 
}
public static function on_get_comments_clauses_cb($clauses, $query){
    global $wpdb;
    $meta_alias = 'commmeta_status';
    $clauses['join'] .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->commentmeta} {$meta_alias}"
        . " ON ( {$wpdb->comments}.comment_ID = {$meta_alias}.comment_id AND {$meta_alias}.meta_key = 'status' )";
    $clauses['where'] .= " AND ({$meta_alias}.comment_id IS NULL OR {$meta_alias}.meta_value != 'ended')";
    return $clauses;
}
```